# why double click is needed to play iframe video using JS

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe youtube video which I am trying to click using a Tag. I got everything to work however I need to click on the image twice in order for the video to play. How can I make it a single click? Is it a focus issue to iframe?

```
<center><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addto" id="playvideo" target="_self" onclick="someFunction2()">
    <img src="www.pngegg.com/pngimages/299/1011/png-clipart-moringa-leaf.png" width="300">
      
</a></center>




<script>
 function someFunction2(){

 $("#playvideo").click(function(){
 $("#widget2")[0].src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtdGWMH28ns?autoplay=1";
    });
 }
```

I wish to click on the image with a single click to play the video rather click on it twice to play the video. any help

Comment: `<img src="www.pngegg.com` <-- This isn't a valid `src=""`, you need the `https://` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick handler `someFunction2` attaches a click handler to your link, but doesn't actually trigger that handler. That attached click handler then plays the video when you click a second time. This is why it takes two clicks -> the first one to attach the handler that actually triggers the video, and the second to trigger the video.

If you want the video to play on the first click then you can simplify your code like

```
function someFunction2(){
    $("#widget2")[0].src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtdGWMH28ns?autoplay=1";
}
```

Comment: worked! appreciated it. I'm not sure why I complicated it. thank you!

Comment: Perfect! or you can get rid of the `someFunction2` altogether and just have `$("#playvideo").click(function(){
 $("#widget2")[0].src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtdGWMH28ns?autoplay=1";
    });`  in your JavaScript. So it binds the handler at the time of page load itself.